# Unable to see hidden text in tmux?

Tags: vim, tmux

I use vim as my text editor in Ubuntu 20.4LTS.
Vim works fine while I'm writing code.
But, if I run tmux using vim some of the **text is hidden**.
What changes do i make to my configuration file.[image]
1 pic - vim
2 pic - Tmux
Suggestions!

Comment: Text is there but the color is very dark, try changing the color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the following in vimrc:

```
set background=dark
set t_Co=256
```

Comment: Should be no need to set t_Co, as it is automatically determined from terminfo database